# all URLs with no trailing slash redirect to include slash

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, content-management-system

Just started a new job and the company website is built on Wordpress. All URLs seem to have a trailing backslash for example https://www.digitallearninginstitute.com/courses/professional-diploma/

We are moving to a different CMS and I want to get rid of these so the URLs are https://www.digitallearninginstitute.com/courses/professional-diploma

From what I can find out this was a requested redirect (I think maybe setup in Wordpress or AWS) where any URLs that dont have the backslash it adds a backslash.

looking at GSC I see a URL that is indexed without a backslash and the version that has the backslash is not indexed which is good from a duplicated content POV however looking at another page its the opposite (version with the backslash is indexed, non backslash isnt indexed)

Question: whats the best practice for moving CMS systems - ideally I dont want to have the backslashes and we are changing the URL slugs (not ideal but we need to)

so for the URL https://www.digitallearninginstitute.com/courses/professional-diploma/ this is changing to https://www.digitallearninginstitute.com/courses/digital-learning-design I was going to setup a redirect from https://www.digitallearninginstitute.com/courses/professional-diploma/ to the new URL and then https://www.digitallearninginstitute.com/courses/professional-diploma (without backslash which gets redirected to the version WITH a redirect) change this to also redirect to the new URL.

Confusing I know but struggling to see the best way forward to make sure I can change the URLs, include redirects where needed without causing 404s.

Thanks

Hopefully with the above solution I can have the old URLs redirect successfully to the new URLs with minimal SEO issues

Comment: If you are doing the redirects in htaccess - you can just make the slash optional for the redirect. simple regex rule.